Visual Studio Git Diff Margin not working
I installed Git Diff Margin plugin in Visual Studio. but it does not show git information.
I'm using Visual Studio 2022 & use Fork Git. Git History on Visual Studio is working, so I thought the git link worked.

here not show git information on the method.

Not show git changes. how to set it?
I'm looking at Github, it shows like this:


It should display mark in the gutter when you do changes in a tracked file. Are you editing the file?

@Philippe no , editing or not edit always not display
